# Does GAE support me having unlimited subdomains?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I want to run my service on google app engine (python), do they all me to create my own custom subdomains easily and without any limit?

For example, my service will run on my custom domain:

```
www.example.com
```

For each customer I will create their own custom domain like:

```
customer1.example.com
```

I may have 1000's of customers, so this would have to be easily done using an API call or they allow wildcards.

My application will analyze the subdomain and lookup the customer.

This will be a single application that will handle all subdomains.

Comment: if you're going to analyze subdomains, then have nothing with gae custom domains, right? you need to point all subdomains to a service which will do that resolving, but you have to implement it by yourself

Comment: You might be interested in the answer i wrote to a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840752 . Simply put and as Igor said it: You must provide the custom domains to Google via the developer console, you cannot handle domain handleing yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, have the wildcard (*) CNAME record of your domain (i.e. `*.example.com`) point to `ghs.googlehosted.com` in your DNS panel and all requests to any subdomain of your main domain will go to your app (and make sure this is also reflected on the [GAE's Custom Domains Settings Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains) as shown on the screenshot below):

[image]

Then have one of your first webapp2 routes as something similar to:

```
    # match all subdomains BUT www
    DomainRoute(r'<:(?!www\.)[^.]+>.example.com', [
        Route('/', handler=CustomSubDomainHandler)
    ])
```

which will match requests to any subdomains but the `www` one (since you might want to serve your actual app via that one).

And your `CustomSubDomainHandler` could look simmilar to:

```
class CustomSubDomainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        subdomain = self.request.host.split('.')[0]
        # code to look up the customer by analyzing the `subdomain` goes here...
```