# How to create user-specific subdomain on Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have to create user-specific sub-domain for each user in the pattern: user_sub_domain.appspot.com.

For this I have created a new service in app.yaml file by specifying **service:service_name**

I have read the following documentation and conclude that sub-domains can be created:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-requests-are-routed

But I don't exactly know the limit and cost of creating these sub-domains. Also I would also like to know if there is a programmatic or step by step method for implementing this.

Comment: What is the number of users you expect or desire to scale to? Tens? Thousands? Millions?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off getting your own domain name, i.e. `example.com` and then by pointing the wildcard (`*.example.com`) DNS entry to your GAE app - you could create unlimited number of subdomains (i.e. `user1.example.com`, `user2.example.com`) and handle them appropriately in your request handler ([see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051258/)).